# How to let user select the location for downloading a file in asp.net?? To be precise a open file dialog equivalent in asp(Not fileUpload)

Tags: asp.net, openfiledialog

I am downloading a pdf file in my project. I want to let the user decide where to download the File. Quick help is helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

It will display a dialog box in the browser and the user will select on where to save the file

```
protected void DownloadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  String Filepath;
  System.IO.FileInfo file =  new System.IO.FileInfo(Filepath); // full file path on disk
  Response.ClearContent(); // Clear previous content
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
  Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
  Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
  Response.End();
 }
```

Comment: Hi Dyrandz, May I know What is this DownloadFile_Click ?? What is the user control to which the event is associated to ?

Comment: Sorry. It didn't help. It is not displaying any dialog box.

Comment: @Sriram Hi Sriram. Could you please let me know how did you solve this in the end? Could you find any workaround? I'm also struggling with the same problem. But I could only find msgbox alert pop up on webform. But not for `folderbrowsedialog` :( Unable to pop up anything to user to select the desired path where he wants to save the downloaded file

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how your application is serving this PDF file, but assuming that you have some WebForm which is streaming it to the Response, you should set the Content-Disposition header as attachment in order to force the Save As dialog in the browser.

For example:

```
protected void Download(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=example.pdf");
    Response.WriteFile(@"c:\work\example.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Hi Darin, I'm able to download it default folder of browser.  But I want to let the user decide the location to download it.

Comment: That's impossible. You cannot control this from the server.

Comment: Then what's the best way?? Atleast I don't want to hardcode the path.

Comment: The folder in which the user downloads the file cannot be controlled from the server.